# Possible bug in "Low Quality Posts"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality

I'm going through Low Quality Posts for the month at the following link:

https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=month

I scroll to the bottom of the page, and click the "get 30 more" link.  The "month" filter is lost.

If you look at the resulting URL, the `&` are `&amp;` which is why it can't parse further parameters.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome if that helps.

Comment: It may vary by the number of results.  The string at the bottom of the page reads "Showing 30 random posts to review; get 30 more, click the tags in the sidebar to narrow and filter or disable random ordering."

Comment: Seems to be a bug on StackOverflow too.  Should this possibly be moved to a higher level meta?

Comment: can repro this In Chrome dev, but dev is not supported..

Comment: @dangowans - the devs do monitor the child metas so this should be seen here.

Comment: Reproducible with my extensions off, should affect any browser.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the doctype and encoding of the website.  The link in question uses `&amp;` but the page is not set to XHTML.

Comment: @dangowans Copying the URL, replacing all `&amp;` with `&` and browsing there works like a charm (keeps the filter), so that's clearly the issue.

Comment: I'll stop speculating then, and leave it to the experts.

Comment: Looks like this was in the update today.  Thanks StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the latest StackExchange update.